# Comparison of random vectors

Tags: chi-squared-test, random-vector

I feel a little stupid asking this, but anyway: say I've got a random vector $a$ of size $p$ with covariance matrix ${\Sigma_a}$ of size $p\times p$, and another vector $b$ with its cov $\Sigma_b$.

My goal is to check whether $a,b$ are having the same 'origin' - are they escribing the same phenomenon? suppose these are the coefficient vectors of two regression models, are these models describing the same effects?

I was hinted that I should look for some $\chi^2$ test for $z=a-b$, with $\Sigma_z=\Sigma_a+\Sigma_b$, but I lost my way. any ideas?

edit: supposing $H_0:E[z]=0$, can I simply use $2z^T\Sigma_z^{-1}z\sim \chi^2_p$?

edit 2: say I've got distinct datasets $A,B$ with the same $p$ columns. each dataset was used for building a regression model and the resulted coefficient vectors are $a,b$. Now I want to test for their equality.

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are not independent, then you need information about their covariance.  Otherwise, you can construct the $2p\times 2p$ covariance matrix of the concatenated vector $(a,b)$ and use that to test the hypothesis $a-b=0.$ I hope this also makes it clear that $\Sigma_a+\Sigma_b$ is not the correct matrix to work with.  Perhaps the hinter intended that you consider $\Sigma_a \oplus \Sigma_b$ instead.

Comment: how does $z=(a,b)$ refer to the hypothesis that a and be origin from the same distribution? please also note edit 2